# WP_Term_Query - How to search only beginning of term name?

Tags: wordpress, search, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm building a WordPress autocomplete search which uses custom taxonomy terms as suggestions, and I'm using WP_Term_Query to query for the terms from what the user types in the search field.

WP_Term_Query has a parameter called "search" which according to [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) uses the search criteria to match terms and will be SQL-formatted with wildcards before and after. I would need it to only include the wildcard after, so that from the input "ad" it would match "**Ad**daday" and "**Ad**idas", but not "Di**ad**ora" or "Fitness M**ad**" for example. Is this possible to accomplish somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to write a bit more code to weed out the results you don't want and keep just the ones you do. How that would look would depend on the code you already have, but [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) might get you on the right track.

Comment: I'm afraid that approach isn't viable in my case as I'm having lots and lots of combinations of words, so the list is really huge. I would need to do this on the query (with a 'number' limit of 10 for each request) and not after.